# Clear PowerShell console in bash on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, powershell

I download `bash.exe` from [SourceForge](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) and added it to my path in Powershell, but I can't get it to clear the console. `clear.exe` is missing from the zipfile that was downloaded, so it makes sense that that command doesn't work. However, using `Ctrl+L` also does not clear the powershell console.

How can I get the powershell console to clear when I'm using bash in it?

Note: I've tried adding an alias called `clear` to my `.bashrc` as `alias clear=echo <many enters>`, but it doesn't work quite the way I've expected (i.e. only echoes 4 or 5 newlines). Also, `echo "\n\n"` just prints out literal `\n\n`.

Comment: Not a direct answer, is there any reason to not use the Windows Subsystem for Linux if you are using Windows 10 or Server 2019?

Comment: The only reason is that I can't....it's a work computer and I have no administrative privileges.

Comment: There are portable installs of Cygwin available if you don't have access to WSL. https://github.com/MachinaCore/CygwinPortable

Comment: Did you try `cls`?

Comment: Yes. I tried `cls`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: As far as Cygwin @killjoy, I also don't have access to install anything on my computer...hence the hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of a `clear` or `tput` utility, and given that the usual ANSI escape sequences don't work with the (built-in) `printf`, you must call out to either `cmd.exe` or PowerShell to effect clearing the screen:

```
bash$ powershell -noprofile -c cls
```

Using `cmd` is faster, but the problem is that the win-bash invokes external programs by *double-quoting each argument* behind the scenes, which causes a command such as `cmd /c cls` to malfunction; the following workaround *mostly* works, but prints the `cmd.exe` prompt string once after clearing the screen.

```
# !! Clears the screen, but prints the cmd.exe prompt string once.
bash$ echo cls | cmd
```

Comment: My pleasure, @PaulFrater; glad to hear it helps.